# a user bookmark system database design

Tags: database, database-design

my user need to bookmark the articles, videos, pictures posted by the others.

now I have a user table, an article table, a video table.

and I come up with two way to store the bookmark data..

first, I can create three one-to-many table.

[image]

the second way is only create a table and add a category column on it..

[image]

with the first approach, I can store foreign keys to associate with the articles and video table. witch is easier for the orm system

and the second way only need a table, but can't store the relationship..

so. which one should I choose,or Is better???

the third way is something like.

[image]

Comment: I would prefer first approach for reasons of performance and referential integrity but it will depend how you think your system will scale (i.e. will you add many more 'things' that can be bookmarked)

Comment: I just using a simply demo on my question, but definitely many more object can be bookmarked on the future.

Comment: Yes, that's similar to what I mean. user_bookmark will also need bookmark_type and that will be used to connect to bookmark_type_assets, which tells you which assets should be loaded for each bookmark. Again, there's more tables, but if you're using something like Linq, navigation should be simpler. But in the end, you should use what you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with tables that employ both types of relationships. For ease of use, I do not prefer the second method. There is another method you may wish to try, which would be (sorry, no picture):

```
USER
UserId

USER_BOOKMARK
UserBookmarkId
UserId
BookmarkAssetId

USER_BOOKMARK_ASSET
UserBookmarkAssetId
UserBookmarkId
AssetType (Title, href, image, caption, tooltip, etc)
AssetStringValue (nullable)
AssetNumberValue(nullable)
AssetByteArray (nullable)
```

You would get a bookmark like:

```
SELECT * AS UserBookmarkLinks
FROM USER_BOOKMARKS ub
INNER JOIN USER_BOOKMARK_ASSETS uba
    ON ub.UserBookmarkId = uba.UserBookmarkId
WHERE ub.UserId = 12345
AND uba.AssetType = "Link"
```

From there you may have `BOOKMARK_TYPE_ASSETS` which tells you what assets are included with each type and which field in `USER_BOOKMARK_ASSETS` it uses. This is a little more involved with tables, but a lot closer to normalized.